# Why all months are not printing in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When i executed below query

```
DECLARE @I INT=1
while(@I<13)
BEGIN
PRINT DATENAME(MONTH,@I)
PRINT @I
SET @I=@I+1
END
```

I  got output like:

```
January
1
January
2
January
3
January
4
January
5
January
6
January
7
January
8
January
9
January
10
January
11
January
12
```

Why all months names are not printing in the above result? Can anyone specify the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you use `DATENAME(MONTH,@I)`
the values 1,2,3,4... are implicitly converted to `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DATETIME)
-- 1900-01-02 00:00:00

1 - Jan  2 1900 12:00AM
2 - Jan  3 1900 12:00AM
3 - Jan  4 1900 12:00AM
...
12 - Jan 13 1900 12:00AM
```

and `DATENAME` for month part is always `January`

You can use `DATEADD` to get all months:

```
DECLARE @I INT=1
while(@I<13)
BEGIN
  PRINT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @i-1, '2000-01-01'))
  PRINT @I
  SET @I=@I+1
END
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414137)**</kbd>

Comment: Yup I got solution Thanks @lad2025

Answer (score 1):

For [DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174395(v=sql.120).aspx) to work the second parameter needs to be a date and not a number. Using an `int` will automatically convert this number to a day starting from January 1st in 1900 (`@I = 0`):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)    -- returns 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 1)    -- returns 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Therefore, the month will always be January for values from 0 to 30 for `@I` (and a lot of other integer values, of course).

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way to get the **Month Name** when you have the **Month Number**

```
DECLARE @I INT=1
while(@I<13)
BEGIN 
print DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @i , -1 ) )
PRINT @I
SET @I=@I+1
END
```

[See Demo Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414170/get-month-name)